# Ubuntu 12.04 alongside 14.04 and Windows 8.x

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, windows-8

Have successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Windows 8 machine. For running some old OS software I also need Ubuntu 12.04. Had created the partitions, had started installation of 12.04 from the liveUSB by first trying without installing, then launching the installer. Followed all steps and was installing fine when got a message about the `grub` not being able to be installed and a bug report being generated. It never got generated though, so I had not taken note of the problem. restarted computer, `grub` does not see other Ubuntu (only 14.04 and Windows 8.x), but looking at the partition it has some system files on.

Repeating the installation as above, I get a warning that there's already a 12.04 and 14.04 on the machine. so:
  1. do I trust the above warning and treat it as a boot issue OR
  2. considering the installation aborted, wipe the partition clean and restart
  3. other suggestions?

thanks

UPDATE: run a boot-repair and the 12.04 appeared amongst the options. When I open it though it still shows the installer icon on the menu bar. I have tried reinstalling without success. It seems to run. I am proceeding to install the Open Source software i need. I am still doubtful as to how it still shows the installer though....any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your computer tries to tell you that you still have Ubuntu 12.04 It will can be found below your regular (newest) Ubuntu in the grub-loader, try taking a closer look.
By default the Kernels are not overwritten, but a new one added.
This comes in very handy if the new kernel are having trouble with some particular hardware. After a couple of weeks these issues are normally fixed, so we can upgrade again.
In Synaptic you can see which kernals you have, and choose to purge the oldest - when the new ones works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to install Ubuntu 12.04 without bootloader by running

> ubiquity --no-bootloader

in terminal on live-cd and then add it to grub manually using this instructions

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

Comment: thank you i did a fresh install of 14.04 and 12.04 following your directions (ubiquity without bootloader from terminale) but was a bit unsure I would be able to follow the GNU GRUB instructions (my shortcoming, I'm not experienced user enough). Then re-rerun boot-repair on 14.04 to get grub to see 12.04 too (when trying to do the same on 12.04 boot-repair did not work). It seems to have worked fine. so thumbs up for now!